# Can't get .py programs to run properly on windows 10 (They worked fine on Windows 7). Possibly a permissions issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, service

Several months ago I created a program in python to automatically edit and process pictures taken by imaging techs at my company to prepare them to be posted on our website.  Running the program via the python interpreter was intended to be a temporary measure until I could rewrite the code in a language more amenable to this application and get a proper binary together but I had other projects pop up and this ended up going slower than intended, and so, rather than a .exe file, our techs are still double-clicking a .py file to edit their images.  This wasn't an issue until we set up two new imaging stations, both running Windows 10 (The other stations, where the program was built and tested, all run Windows 7), and I was told to install my program on these new stations.  Nothing would run at all unless I ran it as administrator.  I was able to work around some issues but not others and could really use some help.  Here is a breakdown of the program, the problem, and some relevant code samples to hopefully give someone out there an idea of what I should do.

So this app consists of two files.  One is a daemon, installed as a Windows Service, that runs in the background, watching a folder for scans and photos, then running a series of editing functions whenever it sees an image and saving the edited files to another folder.  The second is a simple GUI that allows the imaging tech to start and stop the daemon and make manual edits when necessary.  The core files work fine.  They have been running on 8 imaging stations for almost nine months without a hitch.  The problem is that on these new Windows 10 systems, the programs are somehow "locked out" of the system resources they need to function.  I was able to install the daemon so long as I started the command prompt as administrator (Otherwise I'd get an "Access Denied" error), but it won't run once it is installed.  Whenever I attempt to start it, it starts and immediately stops again.  Additionally, I can start the GUI the same way (Via the Command Line with the Shell opened as administrator) but can't open it by double-clicking or, equivilantly, dragging the file onto python.exe.  In both of these cases, like the daemon, it starts and stops again.

As mentioned before, the daemon and the GUI are installed and working on several computers running windows 7.  This isn't a GUI not opening because I didn't start the loop or something like that.  There is something odd going on here and I don't know what it is, but it appears to be related to some difference in security settings between Windows 7 and Windows 10, but that is merely speculation.  If anyone knows what the real issue might be or some things I could try to solve it, that would be great.

Since I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is here, I am posting minimized code for every part of this that interacts directly with the OS, as well as the installation instructions, copied from my documentation.  Thank you sincerely for any help you might be able to provide.

**The Daemon**

```
class SMWinservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    """This is a windows service that will watch the scan daemon folder and process 
    jpg images as they are scanned.
    """
    _svc_name_ = 'Scan Daemon'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Scan Daemon'

    @classmethod
    def parse_command_line(cls):
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(cls)

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)


    def SvcStop(self):
        self.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.start()
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True


    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self): 

        image_list=[]
        d=0
        def rotncrop(file):                          
            im=comiccrop(filename, r'C:\Users\%s\Pictures\My Scans\processed\comic_%d.jpg' %(desktop, d))
            image_list.append(im)
            os.rename(filename,r'C:\Users\%s\Pictures\My Scans\originals\image_%d.jpg' %(desktop, d))
        while self.isrunning:                       
            for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\%s\Pictures\My Scans\scan daemon\*.jpg' %desktop):
                file_size = os.stat(filename).st_size
                if file_size > 100000:
                    d=d+1
                    time.sleep(1)
                    rotncrop(filename)
            time.sleep(0.5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   SMWinservice.parse_command_line()
```

**The GUI**

```
class maingui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("Virtual Straight Edge")

        self.v = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.lotsofentries=Entry(master,textvariable=self.v)
        self.lotsofentries.pack(side='somewhere')

        self.lotsofbuttons=Button(text='do things', command=self.somefunction)
        self.lotsofbuttons.pack(side='top')

    def somefunction(self):
        stuff happens

root = Tk()
theta=0
gui = maingui(root)
gui.updatetext()
root.mainloop()
```

**Installation Instructions**

```
1. Download anaconda python for windows.
2. Copy the “Virtual Straight Edge” folder into AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3.
3. Open the start menu and right click on “Computer”.
4. Scroll down and select “Properties”.
5. Select “Advanced System Settings”.
6. Select “Environment Variables”.
7. Scroll down to “PATH” and select “Edit”.
8. Add the “Virtual Straight Edge” folder and “anaconda3\python.exe” to your path, separated by semi-colons.
9. If on a scanner, double click on “setup.py”. If on a photostation, double click on “photostation setup.py”. When asked what program to use to run this file, select “Browse” and navigate to the anaconda3 folder. Select “python.exe” and check the box that says “Always use this program to open this type of file.”
10. Allow the setup to run. It should take less than a second. Navigate to the Pictures\My Scans folder and verify that four new folders have been created, named “processed”, “originals”, “VSE Images”, and “scan daemon” (or “photo daemon”).
11. Open the command prompt and change directories to the anaconda3 folder.
12. If on a scanner, install the daemons as windows services by typing “python.exe daemon.py install” and “python.exe cropdaemon.py install”. If on a photostation, type “python.exe photodaemon.py install” and “python.exe cropdaemon (photostation).py install”.
13. Press Ctrl+R and type services.msc in the entry field. This will open the Windows Services Manager. Verify that the “Scan Daemon” (or “Photo Daemon”) and “Crop Daemon” are listed as windows services and close the Windows Services Manager.
14. Create a shortcut to Virtual_Straight_Edge.py and add it to the My Scans folder and the desktop if desired. You are now set up to use Virtual Straight Edge!
```

Comment: Where is `desktop` defined in the service code?

Comment: Where is pythonservice.exe located? Can it find its dependencies, python3X.dll and pywintypes3X.dll? The instructions say to add "anaconda3\python.exe" to `PATH`, but `PATH` should only contain directories, and, to be clear, the entries should never contain quotes.

Comment: You also instruct the user to setup the file association via "select 'Browse' and navigate to the anaconda3 folder. Select 'python.exe'". This creates a broken ProgId that won't include command-line arguments (`%*`) in the command template. The user should either select an existing "Python" progid from the list, or you need more detail instructions to create a proper one. I don't use Anaconda, so I don't know what it sets up by default.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out a solution.  There were two issues here.  The first was that Windows 10 handles administrative program access differently, with programs having to be individually, explicitly run as administrator.  In order to get around this, I created a batch file that navigated to my script directory and started the python programs.  I then placed the batch file in the Windows folder and created a shortcut, which I set to run as administrator and put in an accessible place.  Any program initiated with the batch script then has administrative privileges and runs just fine.

Comment: The Daemon was failing due to a conflict between the newest numpy distro and some of my other libraries, but this was not apparent while the permissions issue was still causing failures.  To deal with this, I just rolled back to numpy version 1.13.1 after installing it with administrative permissions and now it runs without a hitch.

Comment: As far as I know and in my experience, UAC has not changed in general in Windows 10. Maybe your Windows 7 systems have it disabled, or maybe your executable was being autoelevated by some quirky backwards compatibility code in Windows 7. Starting a service should require admin access (given the default service security descriptor), but the GUI application should not, as this violates least-privilege design. Save the files in a directory that grants the required access to a standard user.